# How to Listen to Account Changes in a Solana program?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

For Example there is a change in a account in a program how do i listen to that changes to do something. I tried using webhooks but they listen to transaction's and the account involved in that tx does not gets updated as fast as the webhook get's triggered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [accountSubscribe](https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#accountsubscribe) websocket method to subscribe for changes in a specific account.You can use the [@solana/web3.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/web3.js) library which hides the implementation details of the websocket method.

Here is a snippet on how you can achieve this:

```
import { Connection } from "@solana/web3.js"

// Create a connection
const connection = new Connection(<URL>);

// Subscribe to account changes
const id = connection.onAccountChange(<PUBKEY>, (accountInfo) => {
  // Handle account change...
});

// Don't forget to unsubscribe when you no longer use it
connection.removeAccountChangeListener(id);
```

Comment: "Don't forget to unsubscribe when you no longer use it" is this necissary when the process closes? My unsubscribe requests get a "unsubscribe request ignored" warning if I attempt to tidy (i.e. end subscriptions) upon process close